# Can you search for the immediate previous date you have stored in a database in mariadb?

Tags: date, time, mariadb

(I've chosen this example to simplify the problem)

I have the record of the time and date a person entered and left a room. There can only be 1 person in the room at a time. If I know Joseph entered the room at 16/04/2022 13:55:24, is there any way I can search for the previous person who entered and left the room? I can know for sure that the first date and time that is smaller will be of the person who left that room, but I couldn't find any function that does this in the documentation - thanks in advance

I tried reading all of the documentation about date and time but I can't find what I'm looking for. I'm new to mariadb so maybe this is an impossible or absurd question but I'd like to know because it'd seem fairly easy to do with a function.

Comment: even though this is a simplified example, it is very hard to talk about without an actual create table statement and sample data.

Comment: are you looking for just `select person from foo where bar < '2022-04-16 13:55:24' order by bar desc limit 1`

Comment: what other queries do you perform with this `room` table? [system versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) provides a nice interface for historical data with the ability for current contraints (like uniqueness) to apply also.